# Where did Kuhn write his last thoughts about incommensurability?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language, kuhn, incommensurability

> Kuhn continued to develop his conceptual approach to incommensurability. At the time of his death **he had made considerable progress on a book** in which he related incommensurability to issues in developmental psychology and concept acquisition.

(source: Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)

Where did Kuhn express his last thoughts about incommensurability (in other terms, which book is the above-mentioned quote referred to)?

Comment: According to the [SEP article on incommensurability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/incommensurability/#KuhSubDevInc)  "*They are described in a number of essays and published lectures that were collected in (Kuhn 2000, cf. chs. 3, 4, 5, 10 & 11), and a last as yet unpublished book by Kuhn on incommensurability is still pending (Conant and Haugeland 2000, 2).*"

Comment: A nice commentary on Kuhn's late thoughts about incommensurability is in chapter 3 of [Zammito's Nice Derangement of Epistemes](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/N/bo3634623.html) (paraphrase of Davidson's Nice Derangement of Epitaphs). He cites 1982 address Commensurability, Comparability, Communicability and The Road since Structure. [Chen](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25171092) gives even fuller bibliography. I do not think the "pending" book ever came out.